# Can not append child in JS

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I've managed to change alot of this javascript to work with IE10 but I've run into yet another problem. This time I'm getting a *Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference* on the line of code for the if (this.parent) part.

```
var svgns = "http:///www.w3.org/2000/svg"
this.svgDoc = document.getElementById("SVGDoc").getSVGDocument();
this.grp = this.svgDoc.createElementNS(svgns, "g");
this.grp.setAttribute("id", this.id);

if (this.parent)
   this.svgDoc.getElementById(this.parent.id).appendChild(this.grp); //This Line
else
   this.svgDoc.getDocumentElement.appendChild(this.grp);
```

Really confused to why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Please describe the actual problem in the title. That would be more useful.

Comment: Updated Title to reflect question.

Comment: Haven't you changed getDocumentElement to documentElement?

Comment: I did that sorry, I've updated the code. It's the part that if this.parent is true that doesnt work. `this` is the class itself, i think.

Comment: Your error line number reporting is almost certainly off, the error is in one of the `appendChild` calls below. I would suspect `getDocumentElement`.

Comment: this.parent.id is returning banner0 so i'd imagine that wasn't the problem

Comment: So does this.svgDoc.getElementById(this.parent.id) return something sensible?

Comment: this.svgDoc.getElementById(this.parent.id) returns somethings as i placed it in a temp variable and debugging passed that point in the code.

Comment: And you are sure that isn't null, you could use alert(this.svgDoc.getElementById(this.parent.id)) or alert(temp) to check

Comment: Sorry my bad, The alert is showing null.